# My file is not being created in the mapped drive when I try to create it using progress 4gl

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, mapped-drive

I mapped a drive and tried to generate a text file through progress 4gl in that mapped drive. But file was not generated in that mapped drive. When I tried to generate the same file in a local drive then it was generated successfully. Can someone help me with this problem?

I have attached  the Progress 4gl code to generate text file

this code has the location of local drive

```
procedure p-text-generation:
  
  output to value ("//10.0.0.29/myfolder/abhinit.txt").
  put unformatted
  space(1) "hello from p-text-generation" skip.
  output close.
  
END PROCEDURE. /* p-text-generation */
```

this code has the location of mapped drive

```
procedure p-text-generation:
  output to value ("T:/abhinit.txt").
  put unformatted
  space(1) "hello from p-text-generation" skip.
  output close.
  
END PROCEDURE. /* p-text-generation */
```

Both the logics are running in Appserver.
Without Appserver the mapped path is working fine

The folder myfolder is mapped as T drive in my system

Comment: There is no error in the code that works fine (both solution)

Comment: Do you get any error messages or just no file created? What if you try \\ instead of //?

Comment: i tried // as well but it didn't work.

Comment: you also have the RUN Statement in the procedure?
RUN p-text-generation.

Comment: I think you need to check permissions and that the paths are actually the same. What happens if you run `echo test > //10.0.0.29/myfolder/abhinit.txt` in a command-window?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your path as this:
*(I'm currently using this way on Windows Server)*

```
OUTPUT TO VALUE("t:\abhinit.txt").
```

Answer (score 0):

Mapped Drives only work if you are running directly from prowin.exe  or prowin32.exe.  When running on an appserver, drives aren't mapped and the UNC permission is taken from the user running the progress service in windows